# How can I use scientific notation in SQL scripts

Tags: sql, oracle, constants

I am creating a database in which certain derived attributes are computed using the Universal Gravitational Constant (G), whose approximate value is 6.673 * 10^-11.

I understand that a normal integer constant can be defined using a scalar function as follows

```
CREATE FUNCTION MY_CONST()
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN 123456789
END
```

Thing is, I'm new to SQL and not sure how to store a complex value such as G in there. In popular high-level programming languages like Java, I usually define the value as `6.673e-11` at the top of the editor and call it whenever I need it in my calculations. I would like to know how to simply do the same in SQL.

I really just don't get how to translate the value into SQL code as a constant.

Comment: Try 6.673e-11 . . . you might be pleasantly surprised (your question doesn't mention the database, but some definitely do understand this format).

Comment: Using Oracle's SQL Developer. And you are actually right, that does work. I was overthinking this WAY too much. I don't even need a scalar function anymore. Thanks for your help!